# ¿Por qué no puedo modificar una lista dentro de un for?

Tags: python, iteradores

Recibo una lista que debo recorrer eliminando elementos que cumplen determinadas condiciones. La condición es compleja, pero si pruebo con una condición simple (por ejemplo, que el valor sea impar), tampoco funciona

```
lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for i in range(len(lista)):
    if lista[i] % 2:
        del lista[i]

print(lista)
```

El error que aparece es

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/claudio/.config/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2021.2/scratches/xy.py", line 4, in <module>
    if lista[i] % 2:
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La instrucción `for` de Python tiene el siguiente formato:

```
for lista_variables in expresion:
```

La *expresion* en cuestión debe producir un objeto *iterable*, que es un objeto capaz de devolver sus elementos uno por uno (una lista, por ejemplo, es un objeto iterable).

Hay dos tipos de objetos iterables:

- Los que implementan el método mágico `__iter__()`.
- Los que implementa la semántica de *secuencia*.

En ambos casos el problema se reduce a que para iterar se utiliza información calculada una vez al principio. Si los datos involucrados en el cálculo cambian a mitad de camino (por ejemplo, agregando o eliminando elementos), no hay garantía que el cambio se refleje en el `for`.

En estas respuestas sólo nos ocuparemos del segundo caso, las *secuencias*, lo que abarca objetos básicos de Python: listas, cadenas, tuplas, rangos, bytes y bytesarray.

Notese que un *set* es iterable pero no es una secuencia.

En términos simples, una *secuencia* es un contenedor cuyos elementos se pueden accesar mediante un índice y cuyo largo (número de elementos) es conocido. Estas operaciones e realizan usando los métodos `__getitem__()` y `__len__()`.

En el caso del `for`, el largo de la lista se calcula solo una vez, al principio, con lo que su ejecución es equivalente a lo siguiente:

```
numero = lista.__len__()
i = 0
while i < numero:
    if lista.__getitem__(i) % 2:
        del lista[i]
    i += 1
```

Así se puede apreciar la raíz del problema: estas acortando la lista sin recalcular `numero`.

#### Soluciones

Una alternativa es recorrer la lista en orden inverso. Al eliminar un elemento no se altera la posición de aquellos todavía por revisar:

```
lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for i in reversed(range(len(lista))):
    if lista[i] % 2:
        del lista[i]

print(lista) # -> [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Hemos usado la función básica `reversed()` para invertir cómodamente la secuencia.

Otra alternativa es simplemente crear una nueva secuencia y luego reemplazar la original. Esto permite cualquier tipo de modificación, como inserción de múltiples nuevos elementos en medio de la lista.

```
lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
nueva = []
for x in lista:
    if not x % 2:
        nueva.append(x)
lista = nueva
print(lista) # => [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

Es un error decir que no se puede modificar una lista dentro de un for, como ya demostró el propio Candid Moe con su "iterar en reversa", se puede, solo hay que tomar ciertos recaudos, les dejo otra solución del ejercicio propuesto por él.

```
lista = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
lon = len( lista )
cou = 0

for i in range( lon ):
    if lista[ i - cou ] % 2:
        del lista[ i - cou ]
        cou= cou + 1

print( lista )
```

Comment: Sería más corto así: `for i in range( lon-1, -1, -1):
    if lista[i] % 2:
        del lista[i]`

Comment: Usando comprensión: `lista = [x for x in lista if x % 2 == 0]`

Comment: @CandidMoe, maestro, cada día mi admiración crece, y de a poco, siento que voy creciendo como programador (menos mal, porque si crezco de edad, en un mes soy momia!!), gracias de nuevo.